# I can't open a file I have written 10 secs ago

Tags: c#, xna

When I do this

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:/path/items.gif", temp);
Texture2D thiss = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("C:/path/items.gif");
```

I get a cant open file error. Does anyone know a solution to this?

When I write the file it gets saved, i can open it in explorer and all that, but one line of code further it simply wont open it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

HAve the answer. contentmanager.load only works for solution items.

Comment: have you closed the file and  what error are you getting ?

Comment: Do you get an error with the File.ReadAllBytes method? Which one?

Comment: When I write the file it gets saved, i can open it in explorer and all that, but one line of code further it simply wont open it. sorry for being unclear, had a long night of programming

Comment: Any antivirus running? It could happen if it kicks in at the wrong time

Comment: Nope, no antivirus running. Really a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how the Content Manager works.  The file needs to be added to the Content project before it can be loaded in this way.

Also, when loading content with the Content Manager, you do not specify the file type:

```
Texture2D thiss = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("items");
```

If you wish to load content from file, you can use the [Texture2D.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196945%28XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx) method